# Yii2 class not found

Tags: php, yii2

I am getting the error message "Class ... not found" even though the class exists.  The error happens in the method loginByAccessToken() in yii\web\User class.  Any ideas what may be causing this?

```
public function loginByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    /* @var $class IdentityInterface */
    $class = $this->identityClass;
    $identity = $class::findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type); // <-- Error occurs here.  
    if ($identity && $this->login($identity)) {
        return $identity;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Following is the debug trace:

```
{
name: "PHP Fatal Error"
message: "Class 'common\models\User' not found"
code: 1
type: "yii\base\ErrorException"
file: "C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php"
line: 266
stack-trace: [12]
0:  "#0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\filters\auth\AuthMethod.php(50): yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth->authenticate('???', '???', '???')"
1:  "#1 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ActionFilter.php(71): yii\filters\auth\AuthMethod->beforeAction('???')"
2:  "#2 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(541): yii\base\ActionFilter->beforeFilter('???')"
3:  "#3 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(541): ::call_user_func:{C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:541}('???', '???')"
4:  "#4 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(263): yii\base\Component->trigger('???', '???')"
5:  "#5 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Controller.php(108): yii\base\Controller->beforeAction('???')"
6:  "#6 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(149): yii\web\Controller->beforeAction('???')"
7:  "#7 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455): yii\base\Controller->runAction('???', '???')"
8:  "#8 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(84): yii\base\Module->runAction('???', '???')"
9:  "#9 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375): yii\web\Application->handleRequest('???')"
10:  "#10 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.26-0\apache2\htdocs\csplit\api\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()"
11:  "#11 {main}"
-
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two probable causes.

**First** if you copied the application from a folder to another or if you added an extension in a folder and then you copied  part of the code in another folder, you need to execute `composer update` in the final folder.

**Second**
 controls the namespace of the User clauses use
Watch out for upper and lower case.

Comment: I figured it out.  I accidentally deleted the following line from the web/index.php file: require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');   When I added that line back again, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

After you update namespace of classes you copied. 
You edit `SignupForm` class in function rules:

```
'targetClass' => '\common\models\User'
```

to

```
'targetClass' => 'app\models\User'
```